# Minimal infinity categories in the Segal space picture

Tags: homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff

There is a well-known notion of a minimal Kan complex (see Goerss/Jardine's book) which is generalized to a minimal quasi-category in these notes by Joyal

www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/IMA/Joyal.pdf

(Section 6)

Does anyone know about this construction in the Segal space picture?

More precisely: If I have an $(\infty,1)$-category $X$ modeled by a Segal space (so $X$ is in particular a simplicial Kan complex), is there a minimal model for $X$? And can I build this minimal model such that levelwise it has minimal Kan complexes?

More generally, I would be interested in any procedure replacing a complete Segal space by an equivalent one consisting levelwise of minimal Kan complexes.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: A construction of minimal models with a level of generality which includes classical examples as well as their simplicial versions (e.g. Segal spaces) may be found in Section 5.1 of my lecture notes „Higher categories and homotopical algebra“, available here: http://www.mathematik.uni-regensburg.de/cisinski/publikationen.html I do not know if this provides levelwise minimal models, though (but I would not bet on it).

Comment: Minimal models are unique up to isomorphism because any homotopy equivalence between minimal models is an isomorphism. Hence, if a complete Segal space is level wise minimal and has one object only (up to equivalence), then it satisfies the Segal condition on the nose. Being complete, this means that this is the complete Segal space associated to the nerve of monoid. Therefore, there is no hope to get minimal models which are level wise minimal in general.